# Form action gives an error404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with my app. My action doesn't work. I have Article, ArticleVM (View Model), and ArticleController. When I run my app everything works but adding new Post. It redirect me to an empty site, and gaves 404 in console. I don't know how to fix it. I've looked on google, stack, yt and tutorials. I can't see my bug.
Code from controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ArticleVM article)
    {
        try
        {
            var art = new Article() { Content = article.Content, CategoryId = article.CategoryId, Title = article.Title };
            _applicationDbContext.Articles.Add(art);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.Beep();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");     
    }
```

ArticleVm:

```
namespace Blog.ViewModels
{
public class ArticleVM
{
    public String Content { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
}
```

and my view:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
@model Blog.ViewModels.ArticleVM
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<html>
<body>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        @* //added to block registration!
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
        </li>*@
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
<form asp-controller="ArticleController" asp-action="Create" method="post" role="form">
<ul>
    <li><input name="title" asp-for="Title" /></li>
    <li><input name="content" asp-for="Content" /></li>
    <li><input name="categoryId" asp-for="CategoryId" /></li>
    <li><button type="submit">Post!</button></li>
</ul>
</form>

    }
</body>
</html>
```

After action i get this in my browser:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The framework automatically looks for the "controller" when you supply the name.  So when you do this:

```
asp-controller="ArticleController"
```

It's actually looking for the `ArticleControllerController`, which of course doesn't exist.  Just do this instead:

```
asp-controller="Article"
```

So the resulting URL should include `/Article/` instead of `/ArticleController/`

Comment: Thank you @David! It was very silly and simple bug, but I haven't noticed it. Thanks a lot!